# Module not found from sibling using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
proj-dir
   --package1
     --|--__init__.py
     --|--module1.py
   --package2
     --|--module2.py
```

In `module2.py`, i am trying to import a module from `module1.py` as follows:
`from module1 import class1`

When I run `python package2/module2.py`

I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the module2, you need first to access the top-level directory and then you can reach the package2 folder

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

and then to import the module1 from package1 you need to write

`from package1.module1` and then import the class `class1`

so, the full code should be:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from package1.module1 import class1


p1 = class1()
print(p1.x)
```

**EDIT**
according to the update in the question that you run the program from the proj directory using:

```
python package2/module2.py
```

then the code should be:

```
import sys
import os

currenttDir = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(currenttDir + "/package1")

from module1 import class1


p1 = class1()
print(p1.x)
```

first, you get the current working directory (CWD) in the line

```
currenttDir= os.getcwd()
```

which is proj directory
second, append the directory that contain the module `module1.py` to the list that the interpreter would search in when it get `import` command

Comment: Please check edit i am running from the proj directory